# single-dimensional but 2D behaving array in python

Tags: python, arrays

How to make an array in python which can hold a value and a variable together like we see in for example in `time.localtime()`, where Python returns an array consisting of variable names and their value. I just want same kind of array where it would hold variable names with values of those variables:

```
a = (b=1, c=3,d=5)
```

`a[0]` should return `b` which is 1.

If i put `a[c]` it would return `3` again which is value of `c`.

Comment: So you want an `OrderedDict`?

Answer (score 2):

A [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) might suffice, though you would need to access `c` via an attribute rather than by indexing:

```
In [50]: Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', 'b c d')

In [51]: a = Point(b=1, c=3, d=5)

In [52]: a
Out[52]: Point(b=1, c=3, d=5)

In [53]: a[1]
Out[53]: 3

In [55]: a.c    # <-- note `c` is an attribute
Out[55]: 3

In [54]: a._asdict()['c']    #<-- a namedtuple can be converted to a dict
Out[54]: 3
```

A [Pandas Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) behaves exactly as you desire:

```
In [46]: a = pd.Series(dict(b=1, c=3, d=5))

In [47]: a[0]
Out[47]: 1

In [48]: a[1]
Out[48]: 3

In [49]: a['c']
Out[49]: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

use dictionary in python.
dictionary allows you to store unique keys and there corresponding values.
for ex:

```
dic = {}
dic['item'] = 1
```

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

**OrderedDict**
also see this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: They want to be able to use indexes as well as key values

Comment: ya I didn't see that, wont get the indexes in dictionary.